# Carrier maps between simplicial complexes

Tags: reference-request, simplicial-stuff

Simplicial complexes are useful in proving things about distributed systems. We define and use *simplicial maps* between two such complexes, and these maps also seem to be standard objects of study in pure math. But in distributed computing there is another type of map we consider: (what we call) the *carrier map*, which maps a simplex of one complex to a *subcomplex* of another while preserving set inclusion. Formally, given complexes $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$, a carrier map $\Xi$ between these two is a function $\Xi : \mathcal{A} \rightarrow 2^\mathcal{B}$ where for each $\sigma \in \mathcal{A}$, $\Xi(\sigma) \subseteq \mathcal{B}$ is a subcomplex, and for each $\sigma \subseteq \tau \in \mathcal{A}$, $\Xi(\sigma) \subseteq \Xi(\tau)$.

I'm looking for a mathematical reference on carrier maps. Do carrier maps as defined above appear anywhere in mathematics literature; are they of any interest to mathematicians/have they been studied by mathematicians?

Comment: Without having thought through your actual definition, maybe this is something that can be represented in the algebra of simplicial complexes. e.g. can $\Xi$ be transposed into a subcomplex of $A \times B$ (where $\times$ is the appropriate product to use for simplicial complexes)? This would be analogous to representing a function $f : X \to \mathcal{P}(Y)$ as the subset $\{ (x,y) \in X \times Y | y \in f(x) \}$. There should be a correct "power set" map for complexes, and if carrier maps transpose into subcomplexes, then they should be maps into the power complex.